# Headset not work in ubuntu 12.4

Tags: ubuntu

My headset works in windows 7, but in Ubuntu 12.4 not recognized. In the sound setting in the output tab appears only Dummy output. How can I make my headset work?

Comment: What headset do you use? It is hard to help you without this information.

Comment: I use simple usb headset

Comment: Are the Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 different computers? Or is it dual boot? Which model and manufacturer?

Comment: it is dual boot,Tonsion u80

Comment: I couldn't find the tonsion u80 in any hardware compatibility list. It is very well possible that there's no driver available and it simply won't work (in case it is no simple generic usb soundcard). Or is it's name shown in the sound settings (or something like "generic ..." or whatever)?